# Setup SQL Server in WinXP Machine in VirtualBox

Tags: sql-server, virtualbox

I have windows 8.1 pc, and I want to connect to a Win XP pro with SQL Server 2008 Express instalation in VirtualBox.
Both computers are in network and I can share files, but I can't connect to the SQL Server.

How should I setup the SQL Server Express to connect through SQL Management Studio in my windows 8.1 pc (host)??

Comment: a) enable TCP-IP for sql server b) enable connections other from other addresses than 127.0.0.1 c) make sure your firewall on xp pro is open for port 1433/1444. a) and b) are available in the sql server configuration tool (that's not the studio) c) is in the os

Comment: Doesn't work, all is setup like you say, firewall is off.

Comment: When I press to seek server in the management studio, I can see the server DIDIMO (mi xp sqlserver name), but I can't connect it, I'm using a network bridge in the virtual machine

Comment: Are you connecting via Windows authentication or SQL authentication?  If it's Windows auth, then your "server" machine simply won't recognize the Windows account that you're attempting to log in with.

Comment: Only test with sql autentication, message is not for login,  say that server doesnt exist or is unaccesible

Comment: To test if the SQL port is open:    telnet <ip-adress virt machine> 1433     if there is no response at all (screen freeze no cursor movement) the port is closed.

Comment: you can try turning off the Windows firewall